# Dynamically Casting class and calling appropriate methods

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing a utility which uses some classes defined in a 3rd party library which i do not control.

I would like the to know what would be a good way to handle situations like the one described below :
3rd party library has a base abstract class 'Food' which is extended by 'Appetizer','Entree',"Beverage' and 'Dessert'. (all part of 3rd Party Library)

I am writing a 'WaiterUtility' which has methods to serve each type of food.
I want to avoid an endless chain of *instanceof* checks .

---

`

```
Class WaiterUtility{
   public serveItems(Food[] items)
   {
        for(Food aFood : items){
            //how do i call the sub-class specific methods i wrote below?
        }
    }
    private void serve(Appetizer aFood){//somecode}
    private void serve(Entree aFood){//somecode}
    private void serve(Beverage aFood){//somecode}
    private void serve(Dessert aFood){//somecode}
}
```

`

Comment: You can't. In java, dynamic dispatch is strictly on the _receiver_ of the call, not the call parameters. With that in mind, you'll want to fiddle with your design some more.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this isn't the best design for the problem. However its what comes most naturally to mind for this problem. I guess i'll just do Instanceof check and cast :(

Comment: you don't have to instance check and cast. that's basically a lousy design. What is the sort of thing that WaiterUtility is going to do? Can the operation be abstracted and operate on some data than can be retrieved generically from a Food instance? etc. Lots of different ways to skin this cat

Comment: This is indeed not the most pretty design, but sometimes it's pretty tough to avoid these situations.

Comment: @pvg : WaiterUtility has to do things which directly depend on the subclass. In terms of our example : a 'Dessert' will have to be chilled when served but a beverage has to be poured in a glass. Entree can be served on a plate but needs a business logic to select the correct cutlery. None of these behaviour are ingrained as part of the Food class or its subclass. Its just how 'my' waiter does it. The behaviour of waiter may change based on if he is in a Italian restaurant vs an Indian one.

Comment: @merawalaid that's too vague (and also somehow too literal - an OO model need not, and often should not be a 1-1 mapping to 'real' concepts) to really discuss but it sounds to be you've convinced yourself you need this feature and are designing for it rather than designing with the facilities the language has. Collectively, this ends up being rather the opposite of design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something similar to the following:

```
public serveItems(Food[] items)
{
    for(Food aFood : items){
        Class<?> foodClass = aFood.getClass(); // Get the food's class
        Method serve = WaiterUtility.class.getMethod("serve", foodClass); // Get the method by name and argument types

        try {
          serve.invoke(this, aFood);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { // Should never occur, we're matching it up.
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { // Shouldn't occur, we're in the same class.
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // Handle errors possibly thrown by the serve method.
        }
}
```

Haven't tested this tho.

Note that you should however avoid this, it's terrible design.

Comment: ```serve.invoke(aFood)```?

Comment: @saka1029 oups... duh. Fixed.

Comment: I tried with 'serve.invoke(object_of_waiterUtility,aFood);' . The approach does avoid a lot more uglier code though. so It solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, I would implore you NOT to use reflection as TBotV63 does in his answer (he even says to avoid it). From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

> If it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it.

So, obviously we're inclined to say that all `Food`s can be served, and that any `Waiter` can serve any kind of `Food`. Ideally a good API would therefore expose methods that would be sufficient for a `serve(Food)` method to do the job without knowledge of what kind of food it is. It seems like your question implies that this is not the case, and therefore something more needs to be done.
If the 3rd party library accepts community input then you should try to open an issue or a pull request to add the functionality.
Obviously that's not always possible, so the next best thing to do would be to create an interface (something like `Serveable`) which defines the methods you would need, and then subclass the different types of food while implementing that interface. Then you would have `Waiter.serve(Serveable)`.

This is more work than reflection or many uses of `instanceof`, but it is better OO design.

#### Why reflection is bad

The documentation for reflection points out 3 drawbacks of reflection

1. exposure of internals
2. performance
3. security

While you might not care about 2 or 3, 1 is especially bad.

> ... use of reflection can ... render code dysfunctional and may destroy portability. Reflective code breaks abstractions and therefore may change behavior with upgrades of the platform.

#### Why `instanceof` is bad (in this case)

`serveItems(Food[])` implies to the caller that if you pass it several `Food` items, it will serve each of them. However this is not really the case. We can only serve certain sub-classes of `Food`, and we will have run-time errors if we try anything else. Java is a nice typesafe language, we like compile-time errors much more than run-time errors.
Another downside is that additional code needs to be added to `Waiter` every time a new sub-class of `Food` is added or changed. This becomes a cross-cutting concern and makes the code unscalable from a development perspective.
These are by no means the only downsides/issues, just a couple examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
Class WaiterUtility{
   private Map<Class<? extends Food>, Waiter> waiters = new HashMap<>(); 

   WaiterUtility() {
     waiters.put(Appetizer.class, new AppetizerWaiter());
     waiters.put(Entree.class, new EntreeWaiter());
     waiters.put(Beverage.class, new BeverageWaiter());
     waiters.put(Dessert.class, new DessertWaiter());
   }

   public serveItems(Food[] items)
   {
        for(Food aFood : items){
            waiter.get(aFood.getClass()).serve(aFood);
        }
    }

    private static abstract interface Waiter  {
       private void serve(Food aFood);
    }

    private static class AppetizerWaiter implements Waiter  {
       private void serve(Food aFood){
         Appetizer appetizer = (Appetizer) aFood;
         //somecode
      }
    }

    private static class EntreeWaiter implements Waiter  {
       private void serve(Food aFood){//somecode}
    }

    private static class BeverageWaiter implements Waiter  {
       private void serve(Food aFood){//somecode}
    }

    private static class DessertWaiter implements Waiter {
       private void serve(Food aFood){//somecode}
    }
}
```

Comment: The insanceof easier, but mapping class is quite more structure and easy to understand. You code may be in different classes, and you have just a one to one mapping.